# BootStrap / CSS fix position of a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Hello**, i'm kinda new at css/bootstrap, i'm **learning** actually.
In this case, i will probably need to add some css at "chat_funcs" div, but i don't know what to write to get what i want.

The problem:
[image]

What i want is:
[image]

My code so far:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="chat" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">          
    <span class="titulo">Chat</span>            
    <div class="msg">Mensagem teste</div>
    <div class="msg">Mensagem teste</div>
    <div class="msg">Mensagem teste</div>       
</div>  

<div id="chat_funcs" class="pull-right col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <input class="form-control" type="text">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Enviar">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#chat {
  background-color: red ; 
  overflow: scroll; 
  overflow-x: hidden; 
  height: 80%; 
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0; 
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

Comment: The problem is that, since `#chat` is positioned absolutely, it doesn't take up any space as far as the other elements on the page are concerned. Ergo, the `#chat_funcs` appears where it would have appeared if `#chat` wasn't there. That's obviously not what you want, so why do you need the positioning?

Comment: Hello Mr Lister, thanks for the answer , i'm using it for "force" it stays on right side

Comment: You could just float it right to keep it on the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this you are going to use additional html div container. There're other ways too, but this one came to my mind first.

Here is html markup:

```
<div id="chat-container" class="col-md-3  col-xs-12">  
    <div class="row">
        <div id="chat" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">          
            <span class="titulo">Chat</span>            
            <div class="msg">Mensagem teste</div>
            <div class="msg">Mensagem teste</div>
            <div class="msg">Mensagem teste</div>       
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="chat_funcs" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <input id="message-text" class="form-control" type="text"><br/>
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Enviar">
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is css:

```
#chat-container{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 160px;
}

#chat {
  background-color: red ; 
  overflow: scroll; 
  overflow-x: hidden; 
  height: 80%; 
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block; 
}

#message-text{
    width: 140px;
}
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1nL36na/1/)

I hope this helps